# how to use $_FILES[] in model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using Codeigniter and there is a form which contain input type as text and file. So, for passing post variables from controller to model we used to do this

```
$input=$this->input->post();
```

and i am passing this `$input` in function of model from controller. 
But if i need to pass `$_FILES[]` from controller to model, how i will pass ?

I had heard about upload library of codeigniter, but with how can i give a dynamic name to file while uploading

Comment: store and replace the name thats the logic :) But are you asking for code???

Comment: i got the solution, without passing also we can directly use $_FILES in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same concept

```
$files = $_FILES;
```

Comment: is there any function for it, as it is for $_POST

Comment: None, i recommend that you used the library upload of codeigniter.

Comment: there is a problem with that you can't change the name of file in model after loading the library in controller because there in the controller you have to pass $config

Comment: I can't seem to understand your problem.
But [here](http://pastebin.com/bE8Q0Ddz) is my sample code using the library and renaming the file.

Comment: No, in my controller. If you want to save the info after uploading you can do that after the upload was successfull in the model.

Comment: what name should i use in input element userfile or file?

Comment: depends of the name attribute you use 

`<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />`

Ref : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html